# Allowing CORS for HTTPRequest and CORS for Windows Credentials login. C# and Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core

I'm still quite new to C# and .NET development.
I have this configuration in my Startup.cs program that allows CORS and methods from httprequests as I saw in a tutorial.
Here's my config."

```
 services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            //Cors configuration
            services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy(name: CorsConfig,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithHeaders("*");
                        builder.WithOrigins("*");
                        builder.WithMethods("*");
                    });
            });
 services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            //Cors configuration
            services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy(name: CorsConfig,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithHeaders("*");
                        builder.WithOrigins("*");
                        builder.WithMethods("*");
                    });
            });
            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {

                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                
               
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });
```

I want to add configuration for allowing Windows credentials login, I've achieved this using

```
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
```

Bun when testing, My angular application cannot connectto API anymore. So I tried to use Swagger for debugging. executing one method to auth through username and password I got the username and the generated JWT token. When using a method to log through windows credentials I got windows username and JWT token.
But when I send the same requests from my Angular 14 application, I got the following message.

```
login.component.ts:41 
 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized', url: 'https://localhost:44397/api/Auth/login', ok: false, …}
error:  null   headers: 
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message :    "Http failure response for https://localhost:44397/api/Auth/login: 401 Unauthorized" name: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false  status
: 
401
statusText
: 
"Unauthorized"
url
: 
"https://localhost:44397/api/Auth/login"
[[Prototype]]
: 
HttpResponseBase
```

What am I doing wrong? I can share any information needed

Comment: `config.EnableCors();`

Comment: You're getting an unauthorized error and it has nothing to do with CORS and everything to do with .RequireAuthenticatedUser().

Comment: Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: You need to put [AllowAnonymous] in your controller, your /Auth/login action is under authorize, you should allow unauthorized access

Comment: Like Max said. Your user isn't authenticated yet so it has to be anonymous.

Comment: @Max, the controller is allowed access without authorization, even method can execute without having to login.

Comment: But you added the AuthorizeFilter globally so every controller in your application is under authorize access, so even your Auth controller is under authorize, if you want to let your user the possibility to login you need to set [AllowAnonymous] either on AuthController or Login action

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0 for more info about the [AllowAnonymous] attribute